# TreeMap find the value(s) of a String category without knowing the string?

Tags: java

```
TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> mapName = new TreeMap<>();
```

I'm writing a method for which I need to multiply all the double values pertaining to a String value. As the string not consistent I cannot just call for the values by using mapName.get(stringName). Is there a work around for this?

Example TreeMap:

```
stringA {1, 2, 3, 4}
stringB {3, 4, 5, 6}
```

I do not know the string will be named "StringA" or "stringB", so I need to use the position of the string to return 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 for stringA

Comment: Please provide an example of the map, the string, and the value you actually want.

Comment: What do you mean by string is not consistent?

Comment: @YouKnowWhoIAm I'm writing a method so the String doesn't have a set name. I can't just write 'mapName.get("Example String") I need to call the position of the String.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I edited my original question

Comment: If by position you mean the position after the ```TreeMap``` sorts the strings, then you can iterate through them with ```Map.Entry```, and if you dont want to iterate everytime you want a value, then you can copy them into a new ```TreeMap``` where this time you insert ```counter``` variable as the key

Comment: @YouKnowWhoIAm Apologies, I'm a little confused with your explanation. How would I implement the Map.Entry?

Comment: If the string will either by `"stringA"` or `"stringB"`, then why *can't* you use `Map.get`?  `Map.get` can be used on a value you don't know when you write the code.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suppose there is data in your map of `Strings` and `ArrayLists`, then you can create an empty map with `Integer` as key, which contains the position of the `String` in the `Map`, then you can do the following,

```
TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> mapName = new TreeMap<>();
// I suppose you have data in the map
TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Double>> copyMap = new TreeMap<>();
int pos = 0;
for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Double>> e : mapName){
    // e is the current entry in the map
    copyMap.put(pos++,e.getValue());
}
```

`Map.Entry<>` iterates over the `TreeSet` and for each value `e` we create an entry in the `copyMap` which contains the value as the `ArrayList`.